# Reducing Apache Memory usage and Average Process Size Value

Tags: apache-2.4, php5, memory-usage

I know that question is little long but i choosed to describe each and every aspect which i observed from my end.

I am using a Linux server, OS used is Ubuntu 14.04, all rest configurations are defined below. This Web server is used for serving application built up in PHP, Databse is hosted over RDS. On an average at peak times there are nearly 200 concurrent requests on server, which ends up in 100% memory utilization. Due to this application becomes very slow or sometimes responds back with error. So i followed some steps to get this resolved, which i have listed below, and tried to tune apache and restrict it for odd situations.

### OS

NAME="Ubuntu"
   VERSION="14.04.5 LTS

### Server Configuration

CPU: 8 Cores 
RAM: 15 GB 
Hardware Provider: AWS 
Instance Type: c4.2xlarge

### Apache.Conf Parameters (2.4)

Timeout 300 
KeepAlive On 
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100 
KeepAliveTimeout 5 
HostnameLookups Off 
LogLevel warn 
AllowOverride all (for document root of application)

### MPM USED: prefork

MPM_PREFORK.CONF

StartServers              5 
MinSpareServers           5 
MaxSpareServers           10 
MaxRequestWorkers         256 
MaxConnectionsPerChild    200

### Mods_Enabled

access_compat.load  autoindex.load  mime.load         setenvif.load
alias.conf          deflate.conf    mpm_prefork.conf  socache_shmcb.load
alias.load          deflate.load    mpm_prefork.load  ssl.conf
authn_core.load     dir.conf        negotiation.conf  ssl.load
authn_file.load     dir.load        negotiation.load  status.conf
authz_core.load     env.load        php5.conf         status.load
authz_host.load     filter.load     php5.load
authz_user.load     headers.load    rewrite.load
autoindex.conf      mime.conf       setenvif.conf

### Average Apache process size

Command used:

```
sudo ps -ylC apache2 | awk '{x += $8;y += 1} END {print "Apache Memory Usage (MB): "x/1024; print "Average Process Size (MB): "x/((y-1)*1024)}' <br/>
```

Apache Memory Usage (MB): 7227.66 
Average Process Size (MB): 314.246

### Calculation of MaxRequestWorkers

X = Dedicated RAM which i want to allocate to Apache (13GB):  13312 MB 
Y = Average Process size which i am monitoring from last 15 days over server: 314.246 
MaxRequestWorkers = X/Y = 40 approx

### MPM USED: prefork

Modified MPM_PREFORK.CONF

StartServers              5 
MinSpareServers           5 
MaxSpareServers           10 
MaxRequestWorkers         40 
MaxConnectionsPerChild    8

Now when apache starts, it will start 5 startservers process and each startserver process will start 8 child connections so in total 40 concurrent connections can be made to the server. MaxRequestWorkers are limited to 40, which will not go beyond 40 concurrent requests, Which will prevent in case of DOS, DDOS or protect  server from getting halt by occupying maximum ram of 13GB, leaving 2GB RAM free for server. 
I am also not clear about MaxConnectionsPerChild parameter, please make me correct if i am using this wrong.

### PHP.INI Parametrs (php5)

OLD 
output_buffering = 4096 
max_execution_time = 60 
memory_limit = -1 
log_errors = On

NEW 
output_buffering = 4096 
max_execution_time = 60 
memory_limit = 64M 
log_errors = On

### ISSUES WHICH ARE STILL FACED BY ME

After changing the mpm_prefork_conf memory utilization came down but server responds back with 503 error to many clients due to MaxRequestWorkers parameter. I tried to figure out why my each apache process is using 315MB of RAM, i googled around 2 days and was not able to find the right path to further troubleshoot this. So finally i posted this over here. I have two options now.

1. To optimize the apache average process limit and increase the MaxRequestWorkers limit.
2. To increase RAM and serve clients with same average process size, which i think would not be a right choice.

Kindly guide me with the right suggestions how can i identify and reduce the average process size of apache with php. Please genuine answers only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get much better than this, I'd take the route to use php-fpm, then the non dynamic content load will be much faster and less memory consuming, I've found this [guide (digitalocean.com)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-apache-web-server-performance), that gives good recommendations.
A thing you could check out is to change the keepalive times in apache see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095533/proper-use-of-keepalive-in-apache-htaccess)

Comment: I am looking for any ideas to reduce average process size by apache which is 314MB right now?

Comment: I've no ideas on that, I'm sorry

Comment: The process won't run as per the memory limit given; the limit means that if the process is requesting more RAM, Apache should *not* allow it. What you should be looking at is why and where is it requesting that much RAM and change the code. e.g. if you are loading too much data to memory (which is most probably the case) stop it. In nearly all scenarios that I've see, programmers code it so that the front-end specify the search criteria and the back-end loads all matching records. Instead, select only the column that are to be displayed, and, use server-side pagination

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a lot of memory per apache process. And Ubuntu 14.0.4 was EOL in 2019.

The screaming thing in the config you posted is this:

```
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

Change that to 1. You'll find that at least half your active processes are currently doing nothing waiting for the keepalive timeout.

Start analyzing your traffic - make sure all your static content is cacheable.

Go through your apache config - make sure you're not loading modules you are not using.

Make sure you've set a default timeone for PHP and your scripts aren't disabling error reporting. Check your error logs and clean up the errors. Try tweaking your listenBacklog in Apache.

> MaxConnectionsPerChild 8

Why? This is *very* low. Apache is generally very stable. You should be able to up this to 100 to reduce the number of times Apache needs to fork and thereby increase capacity. If changing this vaule has an impact on application error rates, check you've not got badly coded persistent database connections. If it affects memory usage then make sure your patches are up to date.